# Import checkstyle-configuration from sonar into eclipse-checkstyle-plugin

Tags: configuration, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle, sonarqube

I want to export checkstyle rules from sonar and import them into the checkstyle eclipse plugin. Unfortunately sonar exports the checkstyle rules to a csv file.

But the checkstyle plugin only accepts import of xml files.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get it in checkstyle xml format by navigating to

- Configuration
- Quality Profiles -> select your Profile
- activate "Permalinks" tab

This should give you access to the checkstyle config as xml.

In Eclipse you can even configure the checkstyle plugin to use the URL and fetch always the latest rules over the web.